# Excel VBA Creating/overwriting a new workbook and using the cancel button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro written that take a range from one workbook and copies into into a new workbook, which then saves the newly created workbook (and gives it a name) into the same folder path. When this workbook already exists, (overwriting the workbook), the default windows dialogue box pops up asking if you would like to overwrite, with a yes no cancel selection of buttons. When the cancel button is pressed, a new workbook is created. How do I edit this code so that when cancel is pressed, no new workbook is created? I have pasted the macro below:

```
Sub ExportNewBook()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ThisWB As Workbook
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
On Error Resume Next
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:I100").Copy
  NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
  NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:J").Columns.AutoFit
  NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWB.Path & "\" & NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value & "_Summary"
  NewBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: WORKING CODE SHOWN BELOW

```
Sub ExportNewBook()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ThisWB As Workbook
Dim fname As String
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:I100").Copy
  Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
  Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:J").Columns.AutoFit

fname = ThisWB.Path & "\" & ThisWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A4").Value & "_Summary.xls"
If Dir(fname) <> "" Then
    If MsgBox("Summary output already exists, are you sure you want to overwrite?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Newbook.Close False: Application.CutCopyMode = False: Exit Sub
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Newbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ThisWB.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Select
Newbook.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
Sub ExportNewBook()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ThisWB As Workbook, Newbook As Workbook
Dim fname As String
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook

fname = ThisWB.Path & "\" & ThisWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Value & "_Summary"
If Dir(fname) <> "" Then
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to overwrite?", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
End If

Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
  ThisWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:I100").Copy
  Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
  Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
  Newbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:J").Columns.AutoFit

'This code should be faster since it bypasses the copy-paste buffer
'With Newbook.Sheets(1)
'    ThisWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1:I100").Copy .Range("A1")
'    .Range("A1:I100").Value = .Range("A1:I100").Value
'    .Columns.AutoFit
'End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Newbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that this is the way to go -- there is no reason to create a workbook only to throw it away. There are 2 potential problems with your code. 1) The lack of a file extension in fname might cause problems with the Dir() function. Perhaps OP should add an explicit extension. 2) If the user really does want to overwrite the file, your code still displays the warning. Perhaps NewBook.SaveAs could be wrapped between Application.DisplayAlerts = False and Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Comment: Good ideas John!  I've edited my code to implement #2.  I'll leave #1 to the OP, so they can choose the appropriate extension.

Comment: I appreciate the code. It seems to work other than the fact that it will not name the file correctly. The new book is saving as "_Summary" and ignoring the value in A4 (this is because the values are pasted after the line in code where the file name is saved). I am working on fixing this. Also, when clicking cancel, is there a way to prevent the code from opening a new blank workbook?

Comment: That's because your code says to add a new workbook and take A4 from it (which will obviously be blank).  I've edited my response to fix it.

Comment: Kalev, good response. I had fixed the code exactly how you fixed it. Currently, when I press "yes" to overwrite, it opens a new book with a generic name (ex. "Book12") and does not actually overwrite. I am working through this now.Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem Nick.  Glad I could help!  If it's not saving over, then it's the Newbook.SaveAs line that's probably the issue.  I'd step through the code with F8 and see what's going on.  I also added some code that should be faster to my answer.  It's commented so it won't mess with what you have unless you choose to use it.

Comment: Everything is running smoothly now, thanks again Kalev! I have updated my code up top to show what is working for me, for anyone who might find  this useful

Answer (score 1):

On error resume next is seldom a good idea. If the user selects no or cancel, an error is triggered. Better to handle that error to delete the unwanted workbook (although another idea is to test if a workbook with the target name exists before creating it and, if it does, use msgbox to ask the user if they want to overwrite the file and, if so, only then create the workbook, disable alerts, and only then do saveas).

A problem seems to be that you need to have a filename to kill a workbook. In your situation the workbook doesn't yet have a filename. One solution is to create a safe filename whose sole purpose in life is to kill an unwanted workbook, do saveas again with this name, then kill it. Something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fname As String
    Dim tempname As String
    fname = "C:\Programs\testbook.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Now 'for testing purposes
    wb.SaveAs fname
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    tempname = "C:\Programs\name_i_will_never_use.xlsx"
    wb.SaveAs tempname
    wb.Close
    Kill tempname
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the full code with

1. check if file already exist
2. if exist close the newbook and ask you if the existed file will be opened
3. close the newbook
4. in case of error save the newbook with (error) suffix before the extension file

```
Sub ExportNewBook()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ThisWB As Workbook
Dim NewName As String
Set ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
On Error GoTo err_handler
    ThisWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1:I100").Copy
    NewBook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    NewBook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    NewBook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A:J").Columns.AutoFit
    NewName = ThisWB.Path & "\" & NewBook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A4").Value & "_Summary.xls"
      If Dir(NewName)  "" Then
          If MsgBox("A file named '" & NewName & " already exists." & vbCr & vbCr & _
              MeaName & " will now open??", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
              Workbooks.Open NewName
          End If
          NewBook.Close False
          Exit Sub
      End If
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName
    NewBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    NewBook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
err_handler:
    NewName = ThisWB.Path & "\" & NewBook.Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("A4").Value & "_Summary(error).xls"
    NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=NewName
    NewBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    NewBook.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code did not work. I received an error for clicking no, as well as cancel, then after the custom msgbox opened, all the button gave an error as well and it popped up even when the file did not exist

Comment: the code run, but i missing exit sub. Sorry.
before err_handler put:
ExitHandler: Exit Sub 
and in the end of err_handler: (before end sub) put:
Resume ExitHandler